# My swift iOS app always launching in MainViewController - can't navigate initially in SceneDeletage to LoginViewController

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, swift5

As I said in title, I can't navigate into LoginViewController. I show you my code:

scenedelegate.swift

```
[...]
    class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }


                self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
                //self.window =  UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                guard let rootVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "LoginViewController") as? ViewController else {
                    print("ViewController not found")
                    return
                }
                let rootNC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootVC)
                self.window?.rootViewController = rootNC
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
[...]
```

In my LoginViewController I have only text "FALSE".
In MainViewController I have text "TRUE"
When I try navigate to MainViewController (with arrow), it works, but when I try navigate to LoginViewController, I have output in console : ViewController not found

The storyboard:

[image]

StoryboardsID are fine, because I don't have any exceptions:

MainViewController

[image]

LoginViewController

[image]

How to solve it and navigate to LoginViewController?

Comment: In your project have SceneDelegate class file?

Comment: @RajaKishan Yes. I should move it there?

Comment: Try this UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.... instead of self.window in current code

Comment: @RajaKishan Same effect :/

Comment: Okay, do same things inside the SceneDelegate

Comment: @RajaKishan Can you tell me where? It my first attempt to do something like this.

Comment: Inside this method scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)

Comment: @RajaKishan App crashing :/

Comment: Please attached ss

Comment: @RajaKishan Not need to: 2021-01-17 17:08:14.333188+0100 BikeBoard[540:60185] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <BikeBoard.LoginViewController: 0x151e0e270>.

Comment: @RajaKishan Check my updated question, I found new approach to make it in scenedelegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `guard` clause returns nil because you are casting the LoginVC, which has class `LoginViewController`, to `ViewController` - the class of mainVC.

Change the `guard let` to this

```
guard let rootVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as? LoginViewController else {
                print("ViewController not found")
                return
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats what i wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me too how to make it more good looking?
I just want to handle it inside if, not one outside and one inside.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var rootVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController")
        
        if (false) {
            rootVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController")
        }
        
        let rootNC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootVC)
        self.window?.rootViewController = rootNC
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```